# jQuery mobile div doesn't update

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery 1.6.4 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.0.

When doing:

```
$('#mydiv').html(myobjectcontaininghtml);
```

Only about 5% of the time the div actually updates to show the new html.  Anyone know why this would happen? Works 100% of the time using a computer.  On a phone most of the time the div contents don't change.

For example, I tap a link which calls a function with the code above and the contents of the div remain the same.  I keep tapping the link and eventually it does change.

Note: I've seen other posts that say to add .page() or .trigger('create').  Neither of which helped.

Comment: I disabled ajaxEnabled, hashListeningEnabled, and linkBindingEnabled in jQuery mobile and it fixed the issue.  Not sure which one was needed but I don't need any of those enabled.

Comment: when will the code be executed? if possible post your html code as well.